# EJB3 Unit Testing with embeddable container

Tags: java, ejb

Testing EJB3 using glassfish embeddable container, but this call seems to return null all the time, any ideas?

```
//from JUnit 

EJBContainer ejc = javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer.createEJBContainer();
```

Comment: Make sure you are following all prereq: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19798-01/821-1754/gjlde/index.html

Comment: If the method returned null, it would also have thrown an exception with a stack trace. Without posting that, you'll get answers that will only guess what your problem is. I would suggest posting code that will reproduce this issue, in addition to the stack trace, because that method call always works in my workstation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work using openejb. Here is how to get it to start openejb container for testing. Within your JUnit code, add the following (Ideally, in setUpClass)

```
Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"org.apache.openejb.client.LocalInitialContextFactory");
        InitialContext context = new InitialContext(props);
        MyEJB b = (MyEJB) context.lookup("MyEJBLocalBean");
```

You can now call business methods on your MyEJB object b.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [Jetty](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Jetty_Maven_Plugin)

Comment: OP asked about EJB3 testing, Jetty is a servlet container